# Is there a depth limit in vue?

Tags: vue.js, transition, depth

I have a vue component with a structure like this:

```
<transition name="fade">
<div>
  <div v-if="false">
  </div>
  <div v-else="">
     <div>
         <div>
              <div>no matter what content</div>
         </div>
     <div>
  </div>
</div>  
</transition>
```

it works fine until i add a 4th div inside, even without content as it will throw:

DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.

If I remove the transition tag... it no longer throws the error

so I'm just curious... is there a limit in allowed depth for vue?

Comment: I tried your code using jsfiddle and it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no limit. You can nest any number divs. But I saw your `v-else` condition and that might be the issue.

Replace this:

```
<div v-else="">
```

With this:

```
<div v-else>
```